# On gradle:3.0.0 More than one file was found with OS independent path builddef.lst

Tags: android

i have added a dependency implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1' to my project , but when i try to run my app it says.
On gradle:3.0.0 More than one file was found with OS independent path builddef.lst

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

add this into your build.gradl file in

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'builddef.lst'
    exclude 'version.txt'
    exclude 'isoparser-default.properties'
}
```